# "Non-hexidecimal digit found" when deploying on brownie

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py, brownie

When I deploy my smart contract onto Rinkeby network using Infura and making my private key an environmental variable. I keep getting "Non Hexadecimal Digit Found" error. I have tried adding

0x in front of it,

```
       export PRIVATE_KEY = 0xe7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4
```

with and without quotes

```
      export PRIVATE_KEY = 'e7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4'

      export PRIVATE_KEY = e7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4
```

with 0x in front and the quotes,

```
      export PRIVATE_KEY = '0xe7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4'
```

raw

```
      export PRIVATE_KEY = e7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4
```

It works fine if I hardcode it but i have to use an env variable.

```
       account = accounts.add("e7fe227cfb7cb722e7c016aefa0f34e1c17767f708d6b1071d0ee8f88550eaa4")
```

My Brownie config

```
  dotenv: .env

  wallets:
   from_key: $(PRIVATE_KEY)
```

In my deploy script,

```
     account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key'])
```

Please help.

Comment: I hope this is a throwaway private key just for the sake of example...

Comment: Of course, Its just what I use to learn web3 programming